# Bluetooth Beacon Device Suggestions

Tags: android, visual-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

Hi new to the form always use it but never needed to ask anything, i just need advice on the following. thanks in advance!

Is it possible to connect a Bluetooth beacon to a visual studio c# application and use a android phone to send a message to the beacon where the application updates a database? many devices will be sending messages to the same beacon (my project idea). I know the android and messaging part will work but not sure if i can connect the beacon to the VS desktop c# app.

And this is the beacon i have been looking at, need something with a good range. (contacted manufacture about connecting it as they just show an app to configure. no reply lol)

https://accent-systems.com/product/ibks-105/

Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, what you are describing won't work.  Bluetooth beacons are essentially transmit-only devices.  You can't send messages to them.  All beacons do is transmit a unique identifier.

It's unclear what your project is trying to accomplish here, but you *can* use web services as an intermediary for mobile devices to communicate with a C# Desktop app.  You can trigger this communication to happen when the mobile devices detect the bluetooth beacons.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was thinking it would work the same way as two phones communicating. Instead of

Comment: The above method could i still connect the beacon to a visual studio c# desktop app to control what tags are being broadcast to the phones. Then ill just have to make the android app connect to the server to update a db. Project idea is a beacon attendance app

Comment: Or instead of that could i use the same app to control what tag the beacon broadcasts, signal360 beacon shows i can but asking to be safe. Sorry for all the comments.